# C# Disjointed Link Labels Navigation for TabControl - How to highlight current tab open with link labels

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface

Is it possible to get any value from the currently displayed tabcontrol that is open (displayed)? Trying to highlight the adjacent / corresponding tab / link label.

I am using link labels as navigation for the tabs. The real (ugly top) tabs will hidden when the project is finished.

[image: Link Label Intended Highlight Corresponds With Current Selected TAB]

```
//LINK LABELS CLICK EVENTS TO DISPLAY / OPEN TABS
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            //COLOURS TO BE APPLIED WHEN THE CORRESPONDING TAB IS OPEN
            linkLabel1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            linkLabel1.ForeColor = Color.White;
            linkLabel1.ActiveLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }

        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            txtFirstName.Focus();  
        }

        private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }
```

After @Idle_Mind answer I still was not sure how to bind / wireup the event. This is for anyone else with same question:

```
//LINK LABELS CLICK EVENTS TO DISPLAY / OPEN TABS
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            labels_LinkClicked(sender, e);
        }

        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            txtFirstName.Focus();
            labels_LinkClicked(sender, e);
        }

        private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
            labels_LinkClicked(sender, e);
        }


        //METHOD TO CALL ON EACH CLICK OF LINK LABELS
        private void labels_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkLabel lbl = (LinkLabel)sender;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = labels.IndexOf(lbl);
            foreach (LinkLabel curLbl in labels)
            { 
                curLbl.BackColor = (lbl == curLbl) ? Color.Black : Color.Transparent;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire up the LinkClinked() events to the same event handler like below:

```
    private List<LinkLabel> labels;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labels = new List<LinkLabel>() { linkLabel1, linkLabel2, linkLabel3 };
    }

    private void labels_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkLabel lbl = (LinkLabel)sender;
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = labels.IndexOf(lbl);
        foreach(LinkLabel curLbl in labels)
        {
            curLbl.BackColor = (lbl == curLbl) ? Color.Black : Color.Gray;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Idle_Mind for your help. Minor update I made the above (wire up) change you suggested, changed the not current label background to transparent & made LinkLabel1 bg colour black on form load (linkLabel1.BackColor = Color.Black;). Awesome. Thanks man!